# GLM Repeated Measures, with only two time-points (pre-post)?

Tags: lme4-nlme, repeated-measures, pre-post-comparison

I have a dataset that comprises of the same variable, measured at two different time-points (Pre-treatment and Post-Treatment). I want to check if there is an effect of Age in the results of the treatment.

My first approach would be to go for `lmer`, with the following structure:

```r
ml1 <- lmer(Vbl ~ TimePoint*Age + (1+TimePoint|ID), data=db1)
```

However, it produces the following error:

```
Error: number of observations (=90) <= number of random 
effects (=90) for term (TimePoint | ID); the random-effects 
parameters and the residual variance (or scale parameter) are 
probably unidentifiable
```

So, I thought about another hypothesis, which would be to run a linear model for the difference between pre-post timepoints:

```r
    ml2 <- lm( (Vrb2-Vrb1) ~ Age)
```

So, the questions I have are:

**1.** Is ml2 a suitable replaceable for ml1? It accounts for within individual variability, I would say, and by running it alone (`lm((Vrb2-Vrb1)~1`), I would get the answer to the question 'Does the treatment causes the variable to change.

**2.** In case the intercept is not zero when only the intercept is considered but, is zero when Age is considered, I am not sure what that means exactly.

Comment: I think another common thing I see in literature is called a gain-score model so something like `lm(Vrb2 ~ Age + offset(Vrb1))` (the offset fixes the regression coefficient to 1). This is important if Age is correlated with Vrb1 which can increase Type I error if you fit a regression coefficient) I think the gain-score model is equivalent to `ml2` that you propose

Comment: See  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3466/best-practice-when-analysing-pre-post-treatment-control-designs